# Using entryuuid virtual attribute in openLDAP doesn't read in other software

Tags: openldap

When querying the LDAP in some third party software, I am not seeing the entry `entryuuid`.  On reading, I now understand that this is a virtual attribute.

As this is the only real guaranteed unique field, I was going to use this to map users.  However, since the third party software doesn't see it, it is not working as I had hoped (it sees the accounts, but also lists them as inactive).

Is there a way to make `entryuuid` a attribute in the LDAP instead?  I can find that certain implementations of ldap will allow this, but not how to implement it.

Am I barking up the wrong tree, or can I achieve this?

---

Edit: The same is true of "memberOf" it seems.